# Refrigerator compressor issue?

Tags: refrigerator, compressor

May have been asked and answered already but GE Side by Side working seemingly fine but i have noticed that when the compressor comes on (I am assuming) it is causing a substantial power draw in the condo( lights dim). And I can hear a click.

Any thoughts would be helpful. As I said it is working fine otherwise. It does get very little use as this is vacation property.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unless this is a significant change from when it was first installed, this is likely a result of your wiring, and nothing we could really help you with. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, it works , and you hear a click, so is there a problem? Or a feeling , Electrician’s can’t help feelings but can can explain electrical problems.

Comment: It is a significant change & its not a feeling! Unless of course my brainwaves are making all the lights in the house dim and more crucially get very bright! I guess it could be brilliance on my part. I suppose the question SHOULD have been. Has anyone experienced this surge from a fridge compressor? There are no other major appliances, etc engaged when this happens. The CLICK comment was referencing that I am hearing the compressor functioning. The power company has identified the issue.

Comment: Your original question didn't identify the lights getting very bright. You said the power company identified the issue. What was the problem, an open neutral?  How was it fixed?